# Is the place of "which clause" in this sentence correct?

Tags: clauses

I always have issues with using which clause. I appreciate if sb let me know if the which clause in the sentence below is correct.

> "Sth1 brings about unprecedented challenges to sth2 which can be greatly alleviated by sth3. "

The original sentences were:

> 1. Sth1 bring about unprecedented challenges to sth2.
> 2. These Challenges can be greatly alleviated by sth3.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You correctly didn't use a comma before 'which', which would have made it relative to to the first clause ('Sth1 brings ..'); but it is still ambiguous.  By default it is relative to the immediately preceding NP (sth2), and not to 'challenges'.  It is best to avoid relative phrases after complex phrases.  [and why did you change Sth1 to singular?]

Comment: Changing the sth1 to singular was a typo mistake. Sorry!